# How do I correct a font that doesn't have a name?

Tags: wine, fonts

I bought a font from myfonts.com, and installed it on my system by clicking on the .TTF file I received and in the dialog that came up there was a button that said "Install Font". Seemed to work, but after a while I realized only certain programs were seeing the font. Wine programs, like Photoshop don't see it, OpenOffice doesn't see it. Inkscape does.

I looked in my .fonts folder, and clicked on the .TTF file, and this is what I see:

[image: font dialog]

It can't be a good thing that the "Name" field is blank, and there is a question mark under "Style". I'm guessing the blank name is why it's not showing up in some program's lists, but it may just be a symptom of a deeper misconfiguration.

How do I get this font to be properly named and registered in my system so that it appears in all programs?

Comment: Did the font in the original file you got off myfonts.com have a name?

Comment: @Jamie, the font has a name, Museo Sans Rounded 700, but as far as I can tell, that name isn't in any way connected with the meta data of the file, as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `ttx` tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fonttools
   ```
2. Convert ttf to ttx (XML file)

   ```
   ttx fontfile.ttf
   ```
3. Open it for editing

   ```
   gedit fontfile.ttx
   ```

   Search for `<namerecord nameID="1" ... > ... </namerecord>` (and may be `nameID="4"` too)

   Put the name you want in `<namerecord nameID="1"> here </namerecord>`
4. Save it & Reconstruct the font

   ```
   ttx fontfile.ttx
   ```

**Source:** [Change TTF font name](https://superuser.com/questions/120593/change-ttf-font-name)